# SIM required after iOS update

Tags: sim

I have just updated iPhone to latest iOS. I do not have a phone contract and do not have a sim. I get an error message stating SIM required. How do I bypass this step.

Answer (score 1):

Another method to activate your iPhone is using the iTunes application. Follow the steps below to activate your iPhone without a SIM Card.

1. Download and install the latest version of iTunes from Apple on to your computer.
2. Using an iPhone compatible USB data cable connect your non-activated iPhone to the computer.
3. Run iTunes on your computer and follow the instructions which show up on the screen to activate the iPhone.

That’s all now you can use your iPhone without a SIM card.

Comment: If that was, at some point, true, it is no longer with 11.3.  See [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AATFLdGwuhFK2oqlR_Ze9cnVHp6DS67bCao)